# some keys don't work in the tool window of VS 2010 extension

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vsx

I created a vs 2010 extension with a tool window. I have a browser inside my tool window. 
When i type text in the browser everything works fine but when i click on some keys like "enter" or "backspace" the action is being made on the source code editor of VS and not in the browser inside my tool window.

Any idea why ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question was answered in msdn: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/57eebe60-59c0-471c-9540-7fbb13d0b4e7/

Just follow the example in the last post and it'll work fine.